# Representation of the intersection between a sphere and a plane

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions, intersection

Consider the plane $N: x+y+z-3 q=0$ where $q$ is fixed and the sphere $S: (x-q)^2+(y-q)^2+(z-q)^2=r$ where $r$ is fixed.

I would like to make a 3D plot of $N$ and of $S\cap N$.

Here is my command using the `BoundaryStyle` option. H[image]owever the intersection is poorly represented. I tried to increase to value of `PlotPoints` but i didn't improve the representation. Any thoughts ?

```
q = 1/(1+2+1/2)
rN = 0.01
eqS    = (x-q)^2+(q-q)^2+(z-q)^2
eqNcar = x+y+z-3 q
p      = ContourPlot3D[{(eqNcar)==0,eqS==rN},\
  {x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},{z,-3,3},\
  Mesh->None,ContourStyle->{Automatic,None},\
  PlotPoints->100,\
  PlotRange->{{q-0.2,q+0.2},{q-0.2,q+0.2},{q-0.2,q+0.2}},\
  BoundaryStyle->{{1,2}->{Black,Thick}}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Using the skill of `MeshFunction`, set the `MeshFunction` to `eqS` and set the `Mesh` to `rN`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
q = 1/(1 + 2 + 1/2);
rN = 0.01;
eqS = (x - q)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - q)^2;
eqNcar = x + y + z - 3 q;
ContourPlot3D[eqNcar == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate@eqS], Mesh -> {{rN}}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 6, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Cyan], MeshShading -> {Red, Yellow}, 
 PlotRange -> {{q - 0.2, q + 0.2}, {q - 0.2, q + 0.2}, {q - 0.2, 
    q + 0.2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Region` functionality. As an example:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
q = 1/(1 + 2 + 1/2);
r = 0.01;
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x + y + z - 3 q == 0, {x, y, z}];
reg2 = Ball[{q, q, q}, Sqrt[r]];
reg3 = Sphere[{q, q, q}, Sqrt[r]];
r2 = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
r3 = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg3];

Show[
 Region[Style[RegionDifference[reg1, r2], Blend[{Cyan, Green}]]
  , PlotRange -> {{q - 2 Sqrt[r], q + 2 Sqrt[r]}
    , {q - 2 Sqrt[r], q + 2 Sqrt[r]}, {q - 2 Sqrt[r], q + 2 Sqrt[r]}
    }]
 , Region[Style[r2, Red]]
 , Region[Style[r3, {Thick, Black}]]
 , Boxed -> True
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
 , AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}
 , SphericalRegion -> True
 ]
```

[image]